# How can I ignore all files without an extension in eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

Currently in my .eslintignore I have the following:

```
**/*.json
**/*.svg
**/*.bat
**/*.sh
**/*.html
**/*.png
**/*.txt
**/*.ico
**/*.md
```

How can I prevent eslint from linting files that have no extension?  For example, some of my docker files don't have an extension and I don't want to list them all out explicitly.

Comment: Why is ESLint picking up these files? The best solution is to only tell ESLint to search for files matching JavaScript extensions you use (e.g. ts,tsx,js,hsx,cjs,mjs) instead of telling it to find everything, and then ignoring specific extensions

Comment: doing that in the overrides section like this: overrides: [{files:['*.ts', '*.tsx', ect...]}] am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you can use that in the overrides section or use the `--ext` command line option

Comment: Take a look at [this example file here](https://github.com/evelynhathaway/eslint-plugin-evelyn/blob/main/lib/configs/jsx.js#L16-L24). You can use an empty overrides block to define extensions that eslint should use. You do not need to add rules to the overrides, and you do not need to add eslintignore or use a glob pattern when calling eslint through the CLI.

Comment: Gave that a try: overrides: [{files: ['**/*.{ts,tsx,scss,js}']}]    still not working though, must be some other config somewhere that's overriding that maybe?  Thanks for the ideas though!

Comment: The top-level eslint config's overrides apply last, so it shouldn't be overridden by another config. How are you calling `eslint` in your lint script?

Comment: "scripts": { "start": "react-scripts start", "build": "react-scripts build", "test": "react-scripts test", "eject": "react-scripts eject", "lint": "eslint **"},

Comment: Ahh I found the issue, you're using `eslint **`, try using what I added to the below answer.

Comment: haha yeah, I replied to your answer :)  thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to only tell ESLint to search for files matching JavaScript extensions you use (e.g. `ts,tsx,js,jsx,cjs,mjs`) instead of telling it to find everything, and then ignoring specific extensions.

To tell ESLint to add extensions, you can use the `--ext` command-line option, or use the `overrides` configuration as shown below:

**`.eslintrc.js`**

```js
module.exports = {
  // [Your config here...]
  // Empty overrides block that lists your globs for the 
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}"]
    }
  ]
};
```

Then make sure you are telling ESLint the path you want to lint by using `eslint ./` or `eslint ./src` in your lint script, without using glob patterns for extensions, as running `eslint **` for instance will load every file extension.

**`package.json`**

```json
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ./"
  }
}
```

After you've made these changes, you should no longer need an ESLint ignore file just to disable common file extensions.

Comment: Changing the scripts definition from "eslint **" to "eslint ./" did the trick and the overrides is no longer needed.  Don't really understand why though, but thank you so much!!